# Use Docker to use Py2exe on a Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, py2exe

I have never before used docker, but I have been developing a python application on a mac and have been told that I could use docker to allow me to run py2exe so that it can be turned into an executable windows application. I have tinkered with a few pre-built scripts to do this and keep running into errors.

My questions are: how can I build a docker container to simulate python 3.6.5 for windows.

How can I install the additional python modules into this container (py2exe and the ones in my python app)

Sorry for throwing out such basic question. I know Docker is super powerful but I really just want to use it for this one thing.

Comment: You can't do that. Docker for mac will only run linux containers on the Docker supplied Linux virtual machine. py2exe needs a windows platform to run. I would use a Windows virtual machine instead.

Comment: follow up long after the fact. I did this and it worked great. This comment got me to stop messing around with docker so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image for that, but it use PyInstaller instead of Py2EXE

https://hub.docker.com/r/cdrx/pyinstaller-windows

This image has wine installed, which is used to run Windows apps on Linux